# Enums associated values and generics

Tags: swift, generics, enums, associated-value

I have a enum like this, it contains different initial states:

```
enum InitialState {
    case listTableView(ListTableViewState)   
}
```

I want to use them like this:

```
var tableViewState: ListTableViewState?

let test = ListTableViewState(group: .large, statIntervalBase: StatIntervalBaseModel(stat: "ppc", interval: "24h", base: "usd"), order: .ascending, searchParameter: "", quantityStats: .six)
let test1 = InitialState.listTableView(test)
tableViewState = loadInitialState(inital: test1)
```

This is the generic function I am using:

```
func loadInitialState<T>(inital: InitialState) -> T  {
    let test = inital as! T
    print(test)
    return test
}
```

I get this error of course:

> Could not cast value of type 'InitialState' (0x109466da0) to
>   'ListTableViewState' (0x1094912b0).

How can I access it in the generic function `loadInitialState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for Exception:**

In the below code,

```
let test = inital as! T
```

You are casting `InitialState` type to `T`. And according to your code the type of the generic type `T` is `ListTableViewState`.

The reason `T` is of type `ListTableViewState` is derived from,

```
tableViewState = loadInitialState(inital: test1)
```

Here, `tableViewState` is of type `ListTableViewState`

This is the reason type-casting to a different type fails and throws an exception.

**Solution:**

You can access the `associated value` of an `enum` `case` using the **`switch statement`**, i.e.

```
func loadInitialState<T>(inital: InitialState) -> T?  {
    switch inital {
    case .listTableView(let test):
        return test as? T
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The default case is not needed here since there is only one case. So you could avoid it, and returning nil too. change `as?` to `as!`. `loadInitialState` would return `T` then.

Comment: @Carpsen90 `Default` is used because the question mentioned there can be multiple initial states. And using `as!` might result in a crash in case the type didn’t match. So the code is written for handling the edge cases.

Comment: @PGDev While I agree that using the `as?` operator is the safer route here I think the OP would be better served if you removed the `default` clause. Given Swift `switch` exhaustive cases handling design, the OP would then need to add the missing cases down the road *explicitly* (as opposed to the current, error prone, general `default` case handling code).

Comment: @PauloMattos Agreed. Edited the answer.

Comment: @PGDev ...and check how the compiler feels about killing that trailing `return nil` too ;)